# Does my motherboard support SSD?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, sata

I'm trying to find how to check if particular SSD disc can be used on my motherboard

Motherboard: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H61M-S1-rev-22#ov

Please Suggest if it doesn't.

Comment: Yes you can install SATA SSDs. Don’t expect too much speed as it uses only 3G speed. You can’t directly use M.2 modules. You might also use PCIe cards with SSD, however strangely enough only at x1 speed.

Answer (score 4):

All SATA connections support SATA SSDs.

PCIe connections will support PCIe SSDs if they provide enough channels for the card and are of a recent-enough version.

Other SSD form factors require their specialized connectors in order to be usable.

Comment: please check if this https://www.amazon.in/Kingston-SSDNow-2-5-inch-SUV400S37-120G/dp/B01FJ4UN76/ref=sr_1_4?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1511327691&sr=1-4&keywords=ssd

ssd can support
thanks for help

Comment: Did you miss the "SATA" in the description somehow?

Comment: my mother support SATA 3Gb/s connectors (i guess SATA 2)

Comment: In practice this is correct - although it is conceivable that a vendor locks the bios to only recignise some drives - this is a vanishingly uncommon practice, so it's safe to assume you can - moreso because gigabyte are not primarily a whole system vendor (like Lenovo, Dell it HP)